# How to Create this animation effect (GSAP)

Tags: javascript, gsap

[image: Text]

I'm laterally Stack to doing this animation effect. I Just know this site are create a GSAP Plugin but i don't know how to create this.

Here is the live Website
[Link](https://www.davidwilliambaum.com/)

Thank You

Comment: Please visit [help], take [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output, preferably in a [Stacksnippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: Most the logic for this is not related to GSAP. You need to calculate the distance from the centerpoint of the image to the mouse position and scale and change the z-index of the image(s) based on that distance. It also translates the "camera" based on the mouse position in relation to the viewport.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.